# Billy Leg's Secret Treasure!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, literature

Billy has been following a treasure hunt since he moved. Now, he's stumped! He just uncovered a clue:

> `CLUE: )?006¶5*) 6)05*† )-`

Where does he go now?

Hint 1:

> I didn't pick the name Billy Leg for no reason!

Hint 2:

> What's the full form of Billy? Maybe we can also think about a full form of Leg!

Comment: Have you seen [Code Puzzles: What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)? Some of the advice given there might be useful.

Comment: @Deusovi -- It may be helpful for someone to catch on to the hints in the puzzle.

Comment: I have no idea what Billy Leg hints at (figured it was significant since before your hint pointing it out), but here's to hoping someone figures it out.

Comment: Why the 4 downvotes?

Comment: Exactly I thought this puzzle is good

Comment: You might have people who hate you here that is why.

Comment: I wouldn't go assuming this is anything personal. It's probably because this puzzle didn't really have an accessible 'in'. Presented with only a short ciphertext and a very niche literary reference, people just did not know where to begin. I would recommend at least adding a literature tag as a hint before self-explaining, and maybe even offering different clues that would point towards the Poe story (ideally within the text from the start, then just point to them on first hint). Hey, you win some you lose some. Keep going :)

Comment: Couldn't a less oblique hint like "gur frnepu sbe gur tbyq vf fgvyy ohttvat uvz" (or perhaps something a little more subtle hinting at that) have been added before just going straight in with a self-answer? ... or even leave it a few days - I now see it was an even shorter length of time (just 3 days!) before giving up and answering the question yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the ciphertext and the name Billy Leg, we can ascertain that this is the

> Gold Bug Cipher from Poe's short story (involving William LeGrand). This is essentially a simple substitution cipher.

So we can decode this as

> SULLIVANS ISLAND SC (Sullivan's Island, South Carolina; which is where the Poe story takes place)

So he needs to go to

> Sullivan's Island, South Carolina next!

Comment: Searching for Billy Leg without any additional literary knowledge gets you nowhere close to the clues that this is from a work of literature, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bewilderer -- If someone had read the story, they would also have recognized the characters used in the cipher.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I'm not sure that's the case, considering that a lot of people looked at this and nobody solved it. (I've seen the cipher before and didn't recognize the characters.) Either way, if someone hadn't known of it, they would have absolutely no way of finding this.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Don't be disheartened by the negative feedback on this one, I think the main problem with this one is just that the intuitive leap on the name was a step too far. However the idea was great and your other puzzles are awesome, so don't give up making your puzzles, they are wonderful :)